# How to sum individual elements MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have a row matrix `[a1 a2 a3 a4 .. an]` and I wish to achieve each of the following in MATLAB

```
    1) 1+a1
    2) 1+a1+a2
    3) 1+a1+a2+a3
    4) 1+a1+a2+a3+a4
....
     1+a1+a2+...+an
```

How shall I get them?

Comment: This almost sounds like a homework problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using a for loop, but I am unable to construct it properly, I did 
x = [a1 a2 ... a100]
for n=1:100
s = 1 + x
but it obviously gives 1+a1 then 1+a2

Comment: you might check out https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html

Comment: Then I suggest you post the code that you have and describe what is wrong with it. Then we can help you fix it.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: @ArijeetDutta Please add your code to the question itself; it's impossible to format properly in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of the [`cumsum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) function. If `A` is a vector containing the elements `[a1 a2 a3 .. an]` then

```
B = cumsum([1 A]);
```

contains the terms you are searching for. Another possibility is

```
B = 1 + cumsum(A);
```

**Edit**

If you don't want to use a built-in function like `cumsum`, then the simpler way to go is to do a `for` loop:

```
% Consider preallocation for speed
B = NaN(numel(A),1);   

% Assign the first element
B(1) = 1 + A(1);

% The loop
for i = 2:numel(A)
  B(i) = B(i-1) + A(i);
end
```

or, without preallocation:

```
B = 1 + A(1);
for i = 2:numel(A)
  B(end+1) = B(end) + A(i);
end
```

Best,

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I am looking for a solution that won't use special functions like cumsum

Comment: @Arijeet OK, but you should have said that in your question right from the start. I've updated my answer.